# Show the user details in to equal parts to the screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, user-input, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm passing my user data to the next screen and i want to show the data into equal screen, I tried different methods but an able to find the solution.
Container(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

```
       children: [ Row(
           
            children: [

              commonTitle(context, "Username : ", 20, Colors.black),
              Text('${username}', textAlign: TextAlign.left, style:
```

TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

```
              Row(
                children:[

              Text("Email : ",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Text('${email}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

              Row(
                  children:[

              commonTitle(context, "Contact : ", 20, Colors.black),
              Text('${contact}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

              Row(
                  children:[


              commonTitle(context, "D.O.B : ", 20, Colors.black),
              Text('${dateController}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

              Row(
                  children:[

              commonTitle(context, "Department : ", 20, Colors.black),
              Text('${selectedValue}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

    Row(
        children:[
                commonTitle(context, "Hobbie : ", 20, Colors.black),
                Text('${selectedHobbies.join(",")}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

    Row(
        children:[

                commonTitle(context, "Age : ", 20, Colors.black),
                Text('${range.start.toInt()}-${range.end.toInt()}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),
    Row(
        children:[


                commonTitle(context, "Gender : ", 20, Colors.black),
                Text('${selectedGender}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),),]),

    Row(
        children:[


                commonTitle(context, "Address : ", 20, Colors.black),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  child: Text('${add}',style: TextStyle(fontSize:20)),
                ),]),






     ]),
    )[here is the image of my output ][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE THIS FORMAT INSIDE YOUR NEW PAGE Scaffold

```
 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child:   Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //height of 
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('Your Text'),  
            Text('Your Text'),
            Text('Your Text'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not showing up. I assume you can achieve equal parts by wrapping your widgets in *Flex* and specifying what portion of the container they have to occupy. But if you add an executable snippet or a demo of what you want to achieve, I work on it and edit this answer by adding code.